# Webscraper suddenly stopped working. Potential issues with cloudfare?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've built a simple webscraper below that scrapes some information from the site https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/new-products/standard-whisky every minute or so.

It's been working fine up until today and has suddenly stopped working. Changing to

```
product in soup.select('a'):
```

prints out:

```
[<a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/privacy-pass/ajhmfdgkijocedmfjonnpjfojldioehi" rel="noopener noreferrer">Chrome Web Store</a>, <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>]
```

Could this be an authentication issue caused by Cloudfare? Is there a way around this?

Full code:

```
import ssl
import requests
import sys
import time
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import hashlib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
import json
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

user_agent_list = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
]
for i in range(1,4):
    #Pick a random user agent
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
    #Set the headers 
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

url = []
url = 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/new-products/standard-whisky/'

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

bottles = []
link = []
product_name_old = []
link2 = []
link3 = []


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,features="html.parser")
oldlinks = []
product_name_old = []

for product in soup.select('li.product-grid__item'):
    product_name_old.append(product.a.attrs['title'])
    oldlinks.append(product.a.attrs['href'])

product_size_old = len(product_name_old)
print("Setup Complete", product_size_old)
link4 = "\n".join("{}\nhttps://www.thewhiskyexchange.com{}".format(x, y) for x, y in zip(product_name_old, oldlinks))
print(link4)
```

Comment: This looks like it will require a bit more info. What are you seeing in your response variable? Have you tried using a wait condition in selenium? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Printing out response just prints <Response [403]> I'm unsure if a wait condition would work as it wasn't needed previously?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the site. 403 means your connection was recognized but refused. Likely they changed to prevent scraping.

Comment: @EliotK Any potential way around this?

Comment: Do some experimentation on your local machine. Figure out if you can duplicate what your browser is doing. If not, check out Selenium -- that's gotten me through a lot of issues when trying web scraping.

Comment: They blocked you, try to replace the current User Agent list with new one & see if it works. Moreover, also try to rotate the proxy along with it.

Comment: @Shivam The code isn't working via VPN either.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import trio
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0'
}


async def main(url):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        client.headers.update(headers)
        r = await client.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        goal = [(x['title'].strip(), url[:33]+x['href'])
                for x in soup.select('.product-card')]
        df = pd.DataFrame(goal, columns=['Title', 'Link'])
        print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main, 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/new-products/standard-whisky/')
```

Output:

```
                                                Title                                               Link
0        Macallan 18 Year Old Sherry Oak 2020 Release  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/56447/maca...
1                     Benriach The Thirty 30 Year Old  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/60356/benr...
2             Maker's Mark Kentucky Mule Cocktail Kit  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/61132/make...
3                          Isle of Raasay Single Malt  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/60558/isle...
4   Caol Ila 2001 19 Year Old Exclusive to The Whi...  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/61099/caol...
..                                                ...                                                ...
75                    MB Roland Single Barrel Bourbon  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/60403/mb-r...
76                     Seven Seals The Age of Scorpio  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/60373/seve...
77                    Seven Seals The Age of Aquarius  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/60372/seve...
78     Langatun 2016 Pedro Ximenez Sherry Cask Finish  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/60371/lang...
79  Speyburn 2009 11 Year Old Sherry Cask Connoiss...  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/60411/spey...

[80 rows x 2 columns]
```